# I am having problem will overriding OncePerRequestFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure while processing configuration class [org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:251) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:314) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:246) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:416) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at in.gov.forest.wildlifemis.WildlifeMisApplication.main(WildlifeMisApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jakarta/servlet/Filter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:215) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:630) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:956) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:396) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:342) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:246) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I am trying to implement Jwt token in spring boot 3.2.2 but i am getting the above error. I am getting

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure while processing configuration class [org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean]
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure while processing configuration class [org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean]org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure while processing configuration class [org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean]
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure while processing configuration class [org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean]
```